# Replace all my old xcf files by better compressed versions

Tags: command-line, gimp, script-fu

The xcf "better but slower compression" that came out since 2.10 is pretty darn efficient.
I have many old and heavy xcf files in my hard drive and would like to replace them all by their better compressed version with a terminal command.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mileage may vary. On my latest Gimp 2.8 file:

```
Plain Gimp 2.8 format:       15760K
Compressed Gimp 2.10 format: 11220K
GZipped Gimp 2.8 format:     11756K
BZipped Gimp 2.8 format:      9804K
XZipped Gimp 2.8 format:      9460K
```

The Gzipped/BZipped/XZipped formats are obtained by: `{gzip/bzip2/xz} Gimp2.78-file.xcf`

This produces `Gimp2.78-file.xcf.{gz/bz2/xz}` files **that Gimp 2.8 and Gimp 2.10 can open directly without having to un-compress them first** (these three formats can also be produced directly by Gimp)(*).

So you can save equivalent or more space and still keep a 2.8 compatibility by just running `gzip *.xcf` or `bzip2 *.xcf` or `xz *.xcf` in your directories.

`gzip`/`bzip2`/`xz` are rather standard issue on Linux, but there are Windows/MacOS versions.

You can drop the dot in the extension (`.xcfgz`, `.xcfbz2`, `.xcfxz`), this makes it easier to associate the files with Gimp.

PS: as to writing a script to load/save the images, tough luck, there is no option in the current XCF save API to trigger the 2.10 compression, 2.8 images are re-saved in 2.8 format, and changing layer modes to enforce 2.10 format doesn't trigger compression either.

Comment: oh that's even better! I didn't expect Gimp would read them without prior decompressing with another app. thanks

Comment: btw holy molly the xz compression is really not worth it. In my test file it took 7 times longer to compress than bz2 for a file that turns 99.7% smaller than the bz2.

Comment: and crazy thing: you can compress even more by first exporting the xcf with "better but slower compression" in GIMP 2.10 and then compressing that xcf with bzip 2!

Comment: So my question still has some value : can we perform this new compression from the command line?

Comment: *you can compress even more by first exporting the xcf with "better but slower compression" in GIMP 2.10 and then compressing that xcf with bzip 2!*. Not for me: Gimp210: 11220K, Gimp210+bzip2: 11232K. As to the possibility of scripting, see my augmented answer.

Comment: ok, thanks. Actually you're right, the double-layered compression doesn't compress more. I was mislead by the fact that the Gimp210 compression outperformed bz2 in my test file. In fact the bz2 compression makes a 2.10 compressed xcf a tiny bit larger, which is quite interesting.

Comment: *bz2 compression makes a 2.10 compressed xcf a tiny bit larger,*. Expected behavior. A well compressed file looks like completely random bytes, so cannot be compressed further. The 2nd compression only adds its control blocks tot the output.